# JQuery: Toggle Push/Splice within Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, push, splice

That is what i'm trying to do:

I have a list of divs with the same class, everytime I click on one of the divs I would like to store the ID of the respective div in an array, something like:

```
var array = [];

[CODE]

$("divID").on("click", function(){

  array.push($(this).attr("id"));

[CODE]

});
```

What I want to accomplish is that any other click on the same div push/splice the matching ID within the array. A push/splice toggle by ID I guess...

Pushing the div IDs inside an array is not the problem however removing them seems to be a bit more problematic since I'm only capable of clearing the complete array.

How would I have to loop through the array in order to find the matching ID and toggle it on click?

Thanks!

Comment: A simpler approach would be to add `{ID: 'on'}` when clicking, then update the ID and set to 'off' when clicking again. This way, you don't have to remove any items from the array--simply update its status.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! That approach works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my OP comment, a simpler approach would be to use a `Hash` instead of a simple array. Doing this, you can add `{ID: 'on'}` when clicking, then update the ID and set to 'off' when clicking again. This way, you don't have to remove any items from the array--simply update its status.

For example:

```
var hash = {};

$("divID").on("click", function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");

  // Turns it on
  hash[id] = 'on';               // 'on' or true

  // Alternatively, turn it off
  hash[id] = 'off';              // 'off' or false

  // You can also check its status
  // if (hash[id] == 'on')...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: concerning the original approach:**

I found the answer to the original approach of adding/removing the values of the array here (Reference):

http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/thoughts/post.cfm/jquery-tip-finding-adding-and-removing-values-from-arrays#respond

And this is the code:

```
var index= jQuery.inArray(theValue, theArray);

//If you're not using any other Javascript library that utilizes the $ sign, you can use the $ sign 
//instead of the jQuery namespace

var index= $.inArray(theValue, theArray);
if(index== -1)
   {
     //Value not found in the array.  Add to the end of the array with push();
     theArray.push(theValue);
   }
else
   {

     //Remove from the array using splice(). Splice takes the index value of where you want to start 
     //removing items from the array as the first parameter, and then the number of item you want 
     //to remove as the second parameter.

     theArray.splice(index,1);

   }
```

Worked also out for me, I hope it will help others.